# Cannot Send Mandrill Handlebars Template API

Tags: javascript, email, handlebars.js, mailchimp, mandrill

I am trying to access a Mandrill template which I made using their template builder in the Mandrill app (mandrillapp.com/templates).

As I read their documentation I am led to make an Ajax call as such:

```
{
  "key": "<my api key>",
  "template_name": "<my template name as defined in Mandrill templates>",
  "template_content":[],
  "message": {
    "from_email": "<my from email>",
    "to": <[an array of emails defined above]>,
    "subject": "<my subject>",
    "merge":true,
    "global_merge_vars":[
        {
            "name": "visitorFirst",
            "content": visitorFirst
        },

            "name": "visitorLast",
            "content": visitorLast
        },
        {
            "name": "visitorEmail",
            "content": visitorEmail
        }
    ]
}
```

This returns a 500 error. When I put the content inside "template_content" (which documentation says not to do for handlebars, it at least sends, but does not fill any of the merge variables. I have already set Mandrill to expect Handlebars, not Mailchimp variables.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
"template_content":[]
```

To

```
"template_content":null
```

Problem solved.

Comment: If I set template_content to null the email doesn't send?